# Shell script- best way to read column values and store to variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix

I have below batch start date,start time,end date,end time and status  stored in a variable called line :

```
echo "$line"
batch1 09/09/2016 15:12:00 09/09/2016 16:00:00 success
```

I need to store each coulmn values to various variables : batch_name,start_date,start_time,end_date,end_time,status.

one way of doing it is using awk, but looks cluttered if number of cloumns is very large:

```
batch_name="$(echo $line|awk '{ print $1}')"
start_date="$(echo $line|awk '{ print $2}')"
start_time="$(echo $line|awk '{ print $3}')"
end_date="$(echo $line|awk '{ print $4}')"
end_time="$(echo $line|awk '{ print $5}')"
status="$(echo $line|awk '{ print $6}')"
```

Another way is using while loop, but it wont retain values outside while loop since while loop spawns a sub-shell:

```
echo "$line"|while read batch_name start_date start_time end_date end_time status;do
echo ""
done
```

PS:
I have a file which stores status of many batches. I have to iterate through each line and based on status,end time etc. , need to do some processing :

```
cat batch_status.txt
batch1 09/09/2016 15:12:00 09/09/2016 16:00:00 success
batch2 08/09/2016 09:00:08 09/09/2016 01:56:12 inprogress
batch3 08/09/2016 07:15:28 08/09/2016 01:46:22 failure
```

My final script will look like :

```
cat batch_status.txt|while read line;do
 #read LINE and store each column values to corresponding variable (best way to do it?)
 #do processing based on batch_name,start_date,start_time,end_date,end_time,status
done
```

Comment: `while read -r batch_name start_date start_time end_date end_time status; do echo "do procesing here"; done < batch_status.txt`

Comment: This won't work in bash, since while loop spawns a sub-shell and hence variable values won't reflect outside while loop

Comment: Nope, `while` loop doesn't spawn any subshell, but pipeline creates a subshell.

Comment: Thanks for correction. But  when i try to display the values outside the while loop, unable to see their values

Comment: Not sure what is not working for you but `while read -r batch_name start_date start_time end_date end_time status; do declare -p batch_name start_date start_time end_date end_time status; done < batch_status.txt` is working fine for me.

Comment: yes. inside the loop,I am able to display the values, but when i try to display it outside the loop, variables are not retaining their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
read -r batch_name start_date start_time end_date end_time status <<< "$line"
```

If you want to use a pipe, enable bash's option `lastpipe` to run `while` not in a subshell:

```
line='batch1 09/09/2016 15:12:00 09/09/2016 16:00:00 success'
shopt -s lastpipe
echo "$line" | while read batch_name start_date start_time end_date end_time status; do echo $status; done
```